# How to display in a bounded datagridview a field from another table related to the bounded table?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, datagridview, dataset

please help me with this, i two tables named tblaccess(nID,nRoleID,nModuleID,cAccess) and tblmodule(nModuleID,cModuleName) and i have a datagrid which is bounded to tblaccess. the problem is, I want to display cModuleName from tblmodule instead of nModuleID. please tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired output as below way, just get data by querying between the tables, please bind your datagrid using the data that retrieve from below query, thanks

```
SELECT nID,nRoleID,cModuleName,cAccess 
FROM tblaccess INNER JOIN tblmodule 
    ON tblaccess.nModuleID = tblmodule.nModuleID
```

Comment: thanks..i try it..but if i save the transaction..does it affect the tblmodule? i hope not.

Comment: If you change the Modiule name and save it then you've to handle that too, thanks